# Best way to return more specialized object

Tags: c++, oop

I have a base class `Base` with multiple child classes, e.g `Child1`, `Child2` etc.
Inside this `Base` class I have a method returning a pointer to `BaseDefinition`:

```
virtual std::shared_ptr<BaseDefinition> GetDefinition() { return m_def; }
```

Now parallel to the class tree of `Base`, the `BaseDefinition` class also have childs classes: `Child1Definiton`, `Child2Definition` etc. The `GetDefinition()` implementation of `Child1` will e.g return a `std::shared_ptr<Child1Definition>`.

However the return type of `GetDefinition()` is of course a `std::shared_ptr<BaseDefinition>` and this is also completely right as long as we have `Base*` pointers. But suppose we have a more specialized pointer, e.g `Child1*`, in that case `Child1::GetDefinition()` should have a return type of `std::shared_ptr<Child1Definition>`. How can one achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
struct BaseDefinition : std::enable_shared_from_this<BaseDefinition> {};

class Base
{
private:
    virtual BaseDefinition* DoGetDefinition() = 0; // covariant return type

public:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseDefinition> GetDefinition() {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<BaseDefinition>(this->DoGetDefinition()->shared_from_this());
    }
};

struct DerivedDefinition : BaseDefinition {};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    virtual DerivedDefinition* DoGetDefinition() override = 0; // covariant return type

public:
    std::shared_ptr<DerivedDefinition> GetDefinition() {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<DerivedDefinition>(this->DoGetDefinition()->shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

Here, `DoGetDefinition()` is a private virtual function with a covariant return type. Covariant return type feature works with plain pointers or references only. Virtual functions can be overridden by derived classes regardless of their access (private/protected/public).

`GetDefinition` is a public non-virtual wrapper for it, whose sole purpose is to wrap the plain pointer into a smart pointer. This functions is defined by each derived class. It hides the base class version of it.

`std::enable_shared_from_this` and `shared_from_this()` are needed here to go from `shared_ptr<X>` to plain `X*` and then back to `shared_ptr<X>` correctly.

Basically, this contraption simulates covariant return types for smart pointers. E.g.:

```
Derived a;

// Get Base stuff if accessing through Base.
Base* b = &a;
std::shared_ptr<BaseDefinition> p = b->GetDefinition(); // Calls Derived::DoGetDefinition

// Get Derived stuff if accessing through Derived.
Derived* d = &a;
std::shared_ptr<DerivedDefinition> q = d->GetDefinition();
```

Comment: The implementation of `DerivedDefinition::DoGetDefinition()` will also be used to implement `BaseDefinition::DoGetDefinition()` or how is this pattern suppose to work? Is that even possible as the return types and thus the declarations as well are different?

Comment: @Paranaix Elaborated for you.